# Can't launch Android Studio on Mac OS X (10.5.8)

Tags: macos, android-studio

I have downloaded Android Studio and when I try to launch the application, my tool bar looks like the program is going to start, but then quickly stops.  I don't know how to check/set any system variables.  Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

if you have installed 1.7 jdk you should go to /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/info.plist open JVMOption and change the value JVMVersion to 1.7*