# Android Studio Beta 0.8.0 won't start on OS X

Tags: macos, android-studio

I just downloaded the newly released beta version of `Android Studio`. When trying to launch the application, nothing happens.

The following message is shown in the OS X Console:

> `"com.apple.launchd.peruser.501: (com.google.android.studio.58288[542])` Exited with code: 1"

I am running OS X `Mavericks` with `Java 1.7.0_51` installed.

Any help to resolve this issue is much appreciated :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I solved the problem by following the advice given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18884940/cant-launch-android-studio-on-mac-os-x-10-5-8).

In `/Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/info.plist`, expand `JVMOptions` and edit the value of `JVMVersion` to match whatever version of Java you are using. For some reason, mine was set to `1.6*` even though I never had that version of Java installed. So, for Java version 1.8 one would edit the value to be `1.8*`.

Comment: This is not recommended, as it can break application signatures and other things. See here for the recommended way: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/configuration/osx-jdk